# keyboard navigation for browser console

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

Is there any way to navigate object hierarchies in the developer console of either Chrome, Firefox, or other fairly standards compliant web browser,

[image]

using the keyboard? as you would e.g. in an IDE debugger...

Or can you easily hook in to the console from some IDE to get that convenience?

Comment: I seem to be able to navigate object hierarchies in Firefox. E.g., open the console, `document.querySelectorAll('p')`, click on the NodeList result, which opens a sidebar with a tree view of the result. Clicking once in that sidebar allows me to navigate with the keyboard. Does that accomplish what you're looking for?

Comment: Well it seems firefox is ahead of the curve there... no such thing in Chrome